# bitmap from canvas to OpenGL | Why does this code work in 2.1, but not 2.2 and later androids?

Tags: android, opengl-es, view, canvas, bitmap

I got a code (by Google) like this :

```
    InputStream is = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.icon);
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
    bitmap.recycle();
```

I need to pick an image of SpecialViewGroup (I decided to use Canvas), i've tried a code like this

//-- MY CODE

```
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(400, 840, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);    
    bitmap = SpecialViewGroup.GetViewGroupBitmap;

    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
    bitmap.recycle();

    // SpecialViewGroup.GetViewGroupBitmap(), class extends ViewGroup Code:

    public static Bitmap getDesktopBitmap (){
            Canvas canvas;
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(400, 840, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            this.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;      
    }
```

//-- END OF MY CODE

But I get errors in android 2.2 or higher, while in 2.1 it works correctly. Any Ideas?

Comment: I discovered, that this code works in android 1.6, but not in my 2.2 desire, problem is still actual